# Using TouchesMoved in Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm making a SpriteKit game in XCode using swift. I want to make custom buttons in the menu, and I'm following [this tutorial](https://nathandemick.com/programming/tutorial/2014/09/23/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift.html) to do it. Everything's working fine except the touchesMoved function.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
var touch: UITouch = touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch
var location: CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)

if defaultButton.containsPoint(location) {
    activeButton.hidden = false
    defaultButton.hidden = true
} else {
    activeButton.hidden = true
    defaultButton.hidden = false
}
}
```

Apparently, the "*touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch*" doesn't work anymore in Swift 2. I've searched for alternatives, but I haven't found any that works. How could I replace that line of code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is this:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if defaultButton.containsPoint(location) {
                activeButton.hidden = false
                defaultButton.hidden = true
            } else {
                activeButton.hidden = true
                defaultButton.hidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the tutorial is using `NSSet` rather than `Set<UITouch>` in `touchesMoved`. I wonder if they translated the tutorial from Objective-C to Swift, and missed updating them?

```
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
        withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

[touchesMoved - Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:)

Notice the touches argument is of type `NSSet` in your code, and the Apple docs have it as `Set<UITouch>`.

Once you switch to `Set<UITouch>`, try using `touches.first as! UITouch`

Be careful if it can be nil, I'm not familiar with the user input functions on iOS.

If you allow multitouch later you'll need to check the entire Set, rather than just grabbing the first (and only) UITouch element.

Comment: not sure why this got a down vote, Could have just commented to help the guy change the answer.  NSSet was used in earlier versions of Swift, as Swift evolves more and more, it is going to be using less and less of the old technologies, like NextStep classes, so when using tutorials, it is always good to make sure that the version of Swift you have matches that of the tutorial.